# How to find columns that only have one value - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables, `person(email, first_name, last_name, postcode, place_name)` and `location(postcode, place_name)`. I am trying to find people that live in places where only one person lives. I tried using SELECT `COUNT()` but failed because I couldn't figure out what to count in this situation.

```
SELECT DISTINCT email,
                first_name,
                last_name
FROM person
INNER JOIN location USING(postcode,
                          place_name)
WHERE 1 <=
    (SELECT COUNT(?))
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any point in joining to "location", as it brings in no information not already in "person".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate functions always go with `having`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_value(email) over (partition by place_name),
                first_value(first_name) over (partition by place_name),
                first_value(last_name) over (partition by place_name),
                count(*)
FROM person
INNER JOIN location USING(postcode,
                          place_name)
GROUP BY place_name
HAVING count(*) = 1
```

For more about the window functions (like `first_value`) check out [this tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-first_value-function/).

Comment: I get this error: syntax error at or near "(" LINE 4: count(*). Also could you explain the function of "first_value " and OVER.

Comment: @arthionne sorry, forgot the period;> `first_value` is commonly used with window functions: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-first_value-function/

Comment: Could you edit your answer, so that I can accept it as the answer. And thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @arthionne added, consider upvoting if it was helpful

Comment: I just realized that there are some places with same name but different postcodes, for example 20814 Bethesda and 20815 Bethesda. Do I need to change anything to define a place as the combination of name and postcode?

Comment: Simply in place of `place_name` after `partition by` and `group by` put `place_name, postcode`

Comment: I get this error : column "person.email" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as follows. I find it plain and simple.

```
select p1.* from 
person p1
join 
(
    select p.postcode, p.place_name, count(*) cnt from 
    person p
    group by p.postcode, p.place_name
) t on p1.postcode = t.postcode and p1.place_name = t.place_name and t.cnt = 1
```

How does it work?
In the inner query (aliased `t`) we just count how many people live in each location. 
Then we join the result of it (`t`) with the table `person` (aliased `p1`) and in the join we require `t.cnt = 1`. This is probably the most natural way of doing it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of people here, I found this answer:

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       email
FROM person
WHERE postcode IN
    (SELECT postcode
     FROM person
     GROUP BY postcode,
              place_name
     HAVING COUNT(place_name)=1
     ORDER BY postcode)
  AND place_name IN
    (SELECT place_name
     FROM person
     GROUP BY postcode,
              place_name
     HAVING COUNT(postcode)=1
     ORDER BY place_name)
```